# Search for a missing string in many files of which only some are interested (are target files)

Tags: grep

I have more than 1000 files in one directory, but the files interested for me are half of them! I want to search only these files for certain things very often. Unfortunately it is not possible to match something in FILENAME. 
The only thing I thing of is to match some string that is always presented in "interested" for me files in the example is: "special" .. and make somehow a LIST of these files and search them only in them for some things. Maybe some stacked grep commands ?

My attempt to search for missing string "**line4**" on all files:

```
grep -c 'line4' * | grep -P ':0$'
file2.log:0
file3.log:0
file4.log:0
file5.log:0

# -c count lines that match the string and grep zero ones..
```

For example we have 5 files in one folder:

```
ls -l
file1.log  # interesed file (always contains on some line word: "special")
file2.log  # interesed file (always contains on some line word: "special")
file3.log  # interesed file (always contains on some line word: "special")
file4.log  # NOT interesed file
file5.log  # NOT interesed file


cat file1.log 
line1
special
line2
line3
line4
line5

cat file2.log 
line1
line2
special
line3

cat file3.log 
line1
line2
special
line3
line5

cat file4.log 
line1
line2
line3
line5

cat file5.log 
line1
line2
line3
line5
```

The result should be only file2 and file3, because contains unique string "special" and "line4" word is NOT present in that interested files:

```
file2.log
file3.log
```

Comment: Are you trying to match on "word"s that could appear mid-line or whole lines? Can the strings you're trying to match on contain spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by "merging" two `grep` commands:

```
grep -wl special `grep -wvl line4 *`
```

The internal grep will generate list of files which do not contain string "line4". External `grep` will search for word "special" in to the list of files, generated by first `grep`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE and word boundaries:

```
awk '/\<special\>/{x=1} /\<line4\>/{y=1} ENDFILE{if (x && y) print FILENAME; x=y=0}' *
```

Comment: Give me error :(

awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /\<line4\>{ ...

Comment: It was missing the terminating `/` delimiter on that regexp, fixed now.